# How Kartikeya was Born?

Tags: shiva, parvati, kartikeya

I have read some stories and often they contradict themselves regarding birth of Kartikeya.

In some stories, it has been said that he was born with carnal desires of Shiva and Parvati.

[How kartikeya was Born Quora](https://www.krishnakutumb.com/blog/birth-kartikeya-ashok-sundari-ganesha/)

And in some other stories , it is said that he was born with yoga shakti of Shiva and Parvati.

[Birth Story of Kartikeya](https://www.krishnakutumb.com/blog/birth-kartikeya-ashok-sundari-ganesha/)

I am quite confused, what to believe and which story do I discard. Kindly shed some lights as per the scriptures.

Comment: similarly many stories differ due to [Kalpa Bheda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23817/12304) ...

Comment: You may get answer in this answer  (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35850/3869) @Gamerand